# How to make an algorithm to find a mode in Scilab without using built-in functions and with O(N)?

Tags: scilab

So the code I currently have is:

```
T=[2,3,4,3,4,5,2]
x=1
TA(x)=0
for k=1:n do 
   x=T(k) 
   TA(x)=TA(x)+1 
   k=k+1 
   y=max(TA) 
   if TA(x)==y then 
      disp(x) 
   else 
      disp('There is no mode') 
    end
end
```

It gives Error 21 - Index Invalid in the 6th row

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The input number should be unsorted (as in this case - [2,3,4,3,4,5,2])

Comment: Why the Matlab tag? Would a Matlab or pseudo-code solution also be valid? Does the input only contain positive integers? What counts as built-in function?

Comment: @LuisMendo from what I've read, Matlab has pretty much the same (or at least very similar) syntaxis to Scilab, that's why that tag as well. 
Pseudo-code solution would also be valid. 
Yes, positive integers only. 
By built-in function I mean MODE and SORT functions.

Comment: Do you need O(N) in time, in memory, or both? (I can't think of a way do to it with both restrictions)

Comment: @LuisMendo it should have O(N) in time only.

Comment: Can you use the `max` function (it is linear in time)? Also, is this homework (I don't want to spoil the solution)?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, I can't use max function. 
Well, the idea is that it was a homework and I did it starting with bubble sort and then I had O(N^2). Thus, I'm thinking of the ways how it can be improved to reach O(N).

Comment: `TA(x)` is indexing out of bounds, because `TA` is initialized as an array with 1 value. Initizalize it as `TA = zeros(max(T))`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks a lot! I understand now where my mistake was.

Comment: apparently some tutors are giving these bad assignments to some students. If you want the students to learn the basic algorithms you should give them a low-level language like C, which doesn't have so many features already built-in. Saying don't use Scilab functions doesn't help. Anyway, I think [the tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/learn_c_by_examples/mode_program_in_c.htm) should help.